# Automatic numbering -- place code 1. anywhere in 2. the main 3. body

Tags: numbering

Is it possible to insert a code anywhere in the main body that will generate an automatic number with a period:  `1.`  `2.`  `3.` ?

Instead of automatic paragraph numbering (with lots of restrictions), it would be nice to have a code for automatic numbering without restrictions:  `\autonum` anywhere.

I'm looking to avoid complications with other codes, and I do not want an `outline` feature per se where every new line or paragraph gets assigned a number; and I would like the ability to reset the numbering.  The examples I've tried based upon searches for automatic paragraph numbering do not offer the flexibility I'd prefer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabto}
\TabPositions{0.5in,1.0in,1.5in,2.0in,2.5in,3.0in}

\begin{document}

\tab    1.  \tab     On May 20, 2013, I read the case \textit{Smith v. Smith}.
                     *     The buyer shall beware.
\tab    2.  \tab     On May 21, 2013, I witnessed an incident.

\newpage

1.     \tab     Plaintiff shall deposit the sum of . . .
2.     \tab     Both parties shall prepare declarations . . .

\newpage

\tab     \tab     \tab     1.     \tab     Every good boy deserves fudge.
\tab     \tab     \tab     2.     \tab     It is almost Wednesday . . .

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Also a picture of a desired output might clarify your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is very unclear but

```
\newcounter{foo}
\newcommand\autonum{\refstepcounter{foo}\thefoo}
```

allows you to use `\autonum` anywhere to get a number incremented and printed, which you can `\label` as usual.

Comment: YES!  That is exactly what I was looking for.  The icing on the cake would be a period following each number, and a reset code.

Comment: If the number is page-wise, suggest `\newcounter{foo}[page]` or perhaps using [`perpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/perpage)?

Comment: @lawlist just put a `.` after `\thefoo` in the definition, you can reset the counter with `\setcounter{foo}` or automatically when (say) the chapter increments using `\newcounter{foo}[chapter]`

Comment: @Werner I don't think `\newcounter{foo}[page]` can work in general the page counter is not incremented in the main document body but in the output routine. Other counters such as chapter or section are fine.

Comment: `\setcounter{foo}{0}` -- got it -- thanks.  In the answer from Przemysław Scherwentke, an additional `{}` was used -- which one is better -- with or without please?

Comment: the `{}` doesn't do anything and takes up two bytes:-)

Comment: Thank you `all` so very very much for the help -- greatly appreciated !!!